# Unity Script for Player Movement won't execute

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am currently doing an Tutorial in unity and now I am supposed to incule player movement. First I created in the Hierarchy an empty called Player. In that I created an Capsule. Additionally I added in the Project under Assets a new folder called scripts with an Player C# script, which I attached to the Player. I copied the code from the tutorial and checked it but it won't work and I don't get any errors.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour {
    private void Update() {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W)) {
            Debug.Log("Pressing!");
        } else {
            Debug.Log("-");
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to find errors and also searched in the Internet for solutions but I didn't found anything.
[Here you can see the project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WV82e.png)
[Here you can see the code on the right side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4290.png)

Comment: Do you see any messages in the `Console` tab?